# MySQL Default Value as Expression is Wrong

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am running MySQL 8.0.17 and trying to add a default value to a column definition, specifically a JSON column.

```sql
create table `test` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `notes` json default ('[]')) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

The query executes fine, but when I look at the table structure the default value is listed as "(_utf8mb4'[]')".

This even happens if I set a default value for a `VARCHAR` field, but enclose the string in parentheses.

I've also tried using the MySQL `JSON_ARRAY()` function.

```sql
create table `test` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `notes` json default (JSON_ARRAY())) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

but this puts the "(json_array())" as a string as the default.

I feel like I'm doing this write based on the documentation. Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: mine tells me Error Code: 1101. BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'notes' can't have a default value

Comment: Assigning a default empty array to a JSON column seems to work fine in 8.0.17. See [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57a9cb839d838075eced99d68f0a832a) for your reference.

Comment: How do you visualize the table structure? Did you actually try to insert into the table without assigning a value to the json column and check if the default was applied in the inserted record?

Comment: @nbk are you using > v8.0.13?   @GMB here's an updated one that shows you what I'm talking about.  I visualize them with Sequel Pro, which I thought might be the issue at first, but running `describe table` shows it as well.  might I might not be grasping is that the default value is an expression, not a literal value. I was thinking that my expression would be evaluated and the resulting value would be placed in as the value.

Comment: yes, I'm runninh 8.0.17 and workbench and i tried several json from the mysql website